# the hint in bar chart is not showing the text enclosed in html special characters e.g.<cable>

Tags: javascript, jquery, wijmo

Hint is not showing text enclosed between '<' and '>'

```
require(["wijmo.wijbarchart"], function () {$(document).ready(function () {
$("#wijbarchart").wijbarchart({
hint: {
content: function () {return  this.x + '<cable>' + '\n ' + this.y + '';}
/* here the axis labels enclosed in < and > are not displaying.*/
}
```

the hint in bar chart is not showing the text enclosed in html special characters < and >

Comment: Remove the first comment from the code to the body.

Comment: i want to display text enclosed in these <>, can you suggest a solution. It is  not working even after escaping the brackets

Answer (score 0):

I think its the triangle brackets that are stuffing it up.  Try without them.  If it works then you need to escape the brackets.

```
&lt;  and    &gt;
```

to give you

```
'&lt;cable&gt;'
```

Comment: i want to display text enclosed in these <>, can you suggest a solution. It is not working even after escaping the brackets

Answer (score 0):

You should first escape the brackets and then set `isContentHtml` to true.  Just like below code:

```
hint: {
    isContentHtml: true,
    content: function () {
        return  this.x + '&lt;cable&gt;' + '\n ' + this.y + '';
    }
}
```